# Vertical or diagonal scrolling on UIScrollView

Tags: ios4, uiscrollview, scroll, uiscrollviewdelegate

In my case the method `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` can detect just horizontal scrolling in `UIScrollView` and i want to know how to detect diagonal or vertical scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

To detect the direction of the scroll in, say, scrollViewDidScroll:, look at how scrollView.contentOffset.x (horizontal) and scrollView.contentOffset.y (vertical) have changed from their prior values.  If they've both changed, then it's a diagonal scroll.